# Generating Checkbox Lists with MVC3 using a complex viewmodel and a cross table with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, normalization, one-to-many

I've inherited my first MVC project and it involves using MVC3 on top of Linq to SQL. I've been trying to find a way to generate a check box list based on a many to many relationship involving a cross table.

I have a systemFailureType table that maps to a SystemFailureProblem table via a cross table.

Here is my designer layout for the tables:

[image: Designer Layout]
And here are my models:

```
     [MetadataType(typeof(SystemFailureProblemMetadata))]
    public partial class SystemFailureProblem
    {        
        private class SystemFailureProblemMetadata
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(200)]
            [DisplayName("Problem Description")]
            public String Description { get; set; }

            public IList<xSystemFailureProblemToType> FailureTypeCategories { get; set; }

        }        

}



[MetadataType(typeof(SystemFailureTypeMetaData))]
    public partial class SystemFailureType
    {
        private class SystemFailureTypeMetaData
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(200)]
            public String Description { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

My current view code uses a view model that contains a problem object. So the current code I have for generating the checkbox list looks like this:

```
 @for(int i=0;i < Model.problem.FailureTypeCategories.Count(); i++)
 {
       @Html.CheckBox("FailureTypeCategories["+i+"].ID", false)

 }
```

My main issue is that I'm getting some errors when I try to generate the checkbox list saying that the FailureTypeCategories collection doesn't exist. I suspect it may be related to how I have the models set up currently. My initial thoughts are leaning towards implementing a model for the cross table, though I'm not quite sure how I would integrate that. Is there an different way I should be going about this, or am I on the right track and just missing something?

Edit:

Here is the ViewModel

```
        public SystemFailureProblem problem { get; set; }

        public SystemFailureProblemViewModel() { }

        public SystemFailureProblemViewModel(SystemFailureProblem problem)
        {
            this.problem = problem;
        }
```

The controller method is very simple. It just returns a partial view of the form.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {            
        try
        {
            return PartialView("Form", context.SystemFailureProblems.Single(p => p.ID == id));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
            return PartialView("Form", null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you include the ViewModel code as well as the Controller action that returns this view?

Comment: is your intention to generate a checkbox for each `SystemFailureType` related to the `SystemFailureProblem` that is being edited?

Comment: Yes that would be the ideal situation. I would then also have to figure out how to get linq to generate the corresponding entries into the xSystemFailureProblemToType table as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an idea based on [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) which utilizes Entity Framework, but it wasn't too difficult to translate into LinqToSql classes.

First, I tweaked the ViewModel class. You'll need to store more information in there other than the `SystemFailureProblem` object, such as information pertinent to the collection of `SystemFailureType` assigned to that problem.

```
public class SystemFailureProblemTypeViewModel
{
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string TypeDescription { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I created the logic for the Edit actions (GET and POST). In the GET method, you find out which types are currently selected for the problem (from xSystemFailureProblemToType table) and construct a ViewModel using that data. This ViewModel gets passed to the View along with the `SystemFailureProblem` object.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        SystemFailureProblem problem = (from p in context.SystemFailureProblems
                                        where p.ID == id
                                        select p).Single();

        PopulateSystemFailureProblemData(problem);

        return View(problem);
    }

    public void PopulateSystemFailureProblemData(SystemFailureProblem problem)
    {
        // get all failure types
        var allTypes = from t in context.SystemFailureTypes select t;

        // get al types joined with this problem using cross table
        var problemTypes = from x in context.xSystemFailureProblemToTypes
                           join t in context.SystemFailureTypes on x.SystemFailureTypeID equals t.ID
                           where x.SystemFailureProblemID == problem.ID
                           select t;

        // construct view model collection
        List<SystemFailureProblemTypeViewModel> viewModel = new List<SystemFailureProblemTypeViewModel>();
        foreach (var type in allTypes)
        {
            viewModel.Add(new SystemFailureProblemTypeViewModel
            {
                TypeID = type.ID,
                TypeDescription = type.Description,
                Assigned = problemTypes.Contains(type)
            });
        }

        ViewBag.Types = viewModel;
    }
```

In the POST method, we get a string[] parameter that tells us which checkboxes were checked. It is a list of `SystemFailureType` IDs. Loop through each `SystemFailureType` in the database, determine which ones are selected/unselected, and update xSystemFailureProblemToType table accordingly.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection, string[] selectedTypes)
    {
        SystemFailureProblem problem = (from p in context.SystemFailureProblems
                                        where p.ID == id
                                        select p).Single();

        // get all types joined with this problem using cross table
        var problemTypes = from x in context.xSystemFailureProblemToTypes
                           join t in context.SystemFailureTypes on x.SystemFailureTypeID equals t.ID
                           where x.SystemFailureProblemID == problem.ID
                           select t;

        problem.FailureTypes = problemTypes.ToList<SystemFailureType>();

        if (TryUpdateModel(problem, "", null, new string[] { "Types" }))
        {
            try
            {
                // loop through all types in the system
                foreach (var failureType in context.SystemFailureTypes)
                {
                    // determine if checkbox for current type was checked
                    if (selectedTypes.Contains(failureType.ID.ToString()))
                    {
                        // if no joining record exists (type not previously selected), create a joining record
                        if (!problemTypes.Contains(failureType))
                        {
                            context.xSystemFailureProblemToTypes.InsertOnSubmit(
                                new xSystemFailureProblemToType
                                {
                                    SystemFailureProblemID = problem.ID,
                                    SystemFailureTypeID = failureType.ID
                                });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // if type was unchecked but joining record exists, delete it
                        if (problemTypes.Contains(failureType))
                        {
                            xSystemFailureProblemToType toDelete = (from x in context.xSystemFailureProblemToTypes
                                                                    where x.SystemFailureProblemID == problem.ID &&
                                                                    x.SystemFailureTypeID == failureType.ID
                                                                    select x).SingleOrDefault();
                            context.xSystemFailureProblemToTypes.DeleteOnSubmit(toDelete);

                        }
                    }
                }
                context.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        PopulateSystemFailureProblemData(problem);
        return View(problem);
    }
```

Lastly, I tweaked the View. This code will create 3 columns of checkboxes, the value attribute of each being the `SystemFailureType` ID it represents.

```
<div class="editor-field">
        <table>
            <tr>
                @{
                    int cnt = 0;
                    List<SystemFailures.Data.SystemFailureProblemTypeViewModel> types = ViewBag.Types;

                    foreach (var type in types) {
                        if (cnt++ % 3 == 0) {
                            @:  </tr> <tr> 
                        }
                        @: <td> 
                            <input type="checkbox" 
                                   name="selectedTypes" 
                                   value="@type.TypeID" 
                                   @(Html.Raw(type.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> 
                            @type.TypeDescription
                        @:</td>
                    }
                    @: </tr>
                }
        </table>
    </div>
```

It may not be the most efficient, but I think it effectively solves the most complicated pieces of your problem. Let me know if I missed anything!

Comment: Yeah I had an inkling that I would end up going this direction. I was just hoping there would be a better way using some built in binding, but it looks like that's not going to happen.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure of an easier way. It sounds like you are tied to using Linq2Sql, but if not, I recommend EF because it simplifies some things you are doing here (such as loading related objects).

Comment: So, for creating a new SystemFailureProblem, I would just pass a List of all of the failure types with none selected, correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be your Create action (GET). Your POST would receive a `string[]` containing selected values and iterate the same way we did in the Edit action.

Comment: One issue I ran into was that in order to insert/delete from a table Linq requires an index on the cross table. So I had to add that in.

Comment: A second issue was in the insertion of the new entries into the cross table. We need to check to see if the entry was already in the table before inserting a new entry. Otherwise, duplicate entries are made in the table. While this isn't a problem initially, if we attempt to remove the failure type later you get an error in the delete logic because the query returns multiple rows instead of a single xSystemFailureProblemToType object

Comment: right! i forgot to mention the part about adding a KEY column on xSystemFailureProblemToType

Comment: So basically before the InsertOnSubmit call, add an if(!problemTypes.Contains(FailureType)) so you don't have duplicates.

Either way it's working now. Thanks for the help.